# Silverlight Identity over WCF Custom Binding

Tags: wcf, silverlight, security

We are trying to establish the identity of the user using  silverlight client over wcf service using custom binding. We ave tried numerous configurations etc with no luck. On the wcf services we have looked at the operation context, http context but the identity does not seem to be passed through.

Answer (score 0):

**In the Internet scenario (with ASP.NET):**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560702(VS.95).aspx

The key to this is having the WCF service run in AspNetCompatibility mode, and then using HttpContext

**In the Intranet scenario:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744835(VS.95).aspx

The key to this is configuring the server for Windows Auth, configuring SL client for no auth, and making sure the browser is configured to do Windows auth within the intranet zone.